# Firebase web - get Google OAuth token

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a web application where users can `sign in with Google`.

To the sign-in process I add a scope to be able to access Google Calendar.

Now that the user is signed in, I would like to - in client-side - get their current Google access token in order to - in client-side - make a request and get a list of their events.

Is there a way to get the current OAuth token (no need for refresh token) in order for me to make this completely in the client-side?

Comment: once the user signs in with google then onSuccess callback you get entire user details including the access token. That also depends on how you have implemented google sign in

Comment: Don't repost the same question multiple times please. If you have additional information, add it to your original question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm interested in knowing how to do it on the client side, and on the server side. Those are two separate questions. Please reopen this question